# Service fabric SDK Installation with VisualStudio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I've been trying to install the Service Fabric SDK with Visual Studio 2015 by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started) guide from Microsoft. Once I have it installed I can see in control panel:

[image: Control panel showing installed service fabric runtime and service fabric SDK]

However when I then go to create a new Service Fabric Application project the project is not listed there. Additionally, if I try to clone a project from GitHub and load it into VS it says it is incompatible:

[image: Error thrown in visual studio loading .sfproj project]

Is there any known issues with the current version of Service Fabric SDK and Visual Studio 15?
Thanks!

Comment: why are you using VS 2015? you need an upgrade

Comment: It is highly suggested that you upgrade to a later version of VS. But anyway, what's the exact VS2015 version that you're running? The SDK [requires Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#to-use-visual-studio-2015-requires-visual-studio-2015-update-2-or-later)

Comment: I am trying to convince the people I work with we should upgrade! However, IT is resisting... We are running Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 so I believe it should be compatible